# OpenEJB - exclude single beans

Tags: java, junit, ejb, openejb

I'm testing my application using junit and OpenEJB container to provide context for my beans. It's finding all beans from classpath and starting them. Unfortunatelly there are some beans I would like to remove from context, so I can replace those beans with other implementations, mocking certain functionalities.

I'm aware of `openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude` property.
I even tried to use it as follows `properties.put("openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude", ".*/CommonCache.*");` as it  was sugested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875899/tell-openejb-to-ignore-mdb).

OpenEJB sees this property but bean is still starting as shown in logs below.

```
Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude=.*/CommonCacheBean.*'
Auto-deploying ejb CommonCacheBean: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=CommonCacheBean)
Jndi(name="java:global/ejbs/CommonCacheBean!my.package.ICommonCache")
Created Ejb(deployment-id=CommonCacheBean, ejb-name=CommonCacheBean, container=Default Stateless Container)
```

So there is my question. Is there a way to exclude single bean(s) from OpenEJB context? It doesn't matter to me if it will be achieved this config way or by manual operations in java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested i didn't manage to remove beans from context. Although there is an `unbind()` method in context it does not seem to work on OpenEJB context.
I succeded in replacing beans manually with `rebind()` but it was too late because they were already injected into another beans.

They way i solved my problem was by using annotaion `@Alternative` on mock implementation. I also had to add entries in `beans.xml` to show container those beans and change the way I inject them from `@EJB` to `@Inject`.